# want to use generics type <T>

Tags: java, generics

I want to use generic type `<T>` so that it accepts any kind of objects.
Below is my code sample original code.

```
class Address{
///
}

class Person{

///

}

class Details
{
Map<String,String> addressMap;
Map<String,String> personMap;
...

//getters

//setters

public void updateAddress(String id, String case) {
        this.addressMap.put(id, case);
    }

public void updatePerson(String id, String case) {
        this.personMap.put(id, case);
    }
}
```

I want to modify the class Details using `<T>` so that it takes any kind of objects.
Please let me know the best approach.

Can i introduce the new variable(allObjectMap) as below instead of using individual variables for different objects(addressMap,personMap). Sample code below.

```
class Details<T>
{
Map<T,String> allObjectMap;

//getter & setter
    public Map<T, String> getAllObjectMap() {
    return allObjectMap;
}

public void setAllObjectMap(Map<T, String> allObjectMap) {
    this.allObjectMap = allObjectMap;
}
public void updateAddress(String id, String case) {
       // this.addressMap.put(id, case);
     this.allObjectMap.put((T)id, case);
    }

public void updatePerson(String id, String case) {
        this.personMap.put(id, case);
  this.allObjectMap.put((T)id, case);
    }
}
```

Please let me know the better approach.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you want to accept all kinds of objects then why are you only accepting `String` objects? What does it *mean* to have a `Details<Thread>` or a `Details<Double>` or a `Details<MyApplicationActivity>`? Do you really want any of those to be possible? I suspect your actual requirement may be tighter than that.

Comment: btw: `case` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a parameter name.

Comment: Could you please reformat your code? It's a mess at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you showed is incorrect both by logic, semantic and by design.

The classes you showed aren't even related nor does it come in a "common" handling case.

I have used 2 different classes.

```
class Junior {

}
class Senior {

}
class Details<T> {
    Map<T, String> allObjectMap;

    public Map<T, String> getAllObjectMap() {
        return allObjectMap;
    }
    public void setAllObjectMap(Map<T, String> allObjectMap) {
        this.allObjectMap = allObjectMap;
    }
}
```

In your main method,

```
HashMap<Junior, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Senior, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Details<Junior> juniors = new Details<Junior>();
juniors.setAllObjectMap(map1);
Details<Senior> seniors = new Details<Senior>();
seniors.setAllObjectMap(map2);
```

As you can see it's fairly possible to do it.